# Concatenation of measurements in SQL Database with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, combobox, dropdown

I am developing a web system for a furniture store and I would like to show the measurements of the furniture in this way

[image: Example]

The problem is that I have the measurements in different columns in my database

[image: My Database]

The calls of the CombosBox or Dropdown I made them as a call to a class (ComboHelps.cs)

```
public class CombosHelper : IDisposable
{   
    public static List<MuebleVanitorio> GetMedidas()
    {
        var medidas = db.MuebleVanitorios.Select(m => m.Largo + "" + m.Ancho + "" + m.Alto).ToList();
        medidas.Add(new MuebleVanitorio
        {
            Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio = 0,
            v_Nombre = "[Seleccione Medidas...]",
        });
        return medidas.OrderBy(m => m.v_Nombre).ToList();
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
public class MuebleVanitorio
{
    [Key]
    public int Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio { get; set; }

    public string v_Nombre { get; set; }

    public int Largo { get; set; }

    public int Alto { get; set; }

    public int Ancho { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult AgregarMuebleVanitorio()
{            
    ViewBag.Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio = new SelectList(CombosHelper.GetMedidas(), "Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio", "v_Nombre");

    return View();
}
```

My View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio, "Medidas Mueble", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

I get the following error:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'v_Nombre' and no extension method 'v_Nombre' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

any help for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression on the right side of this statement

```
var medidas = db.MuebleVanitorios
                .Select(m => m.Largo + "" + m.Ancho + "" + m.Alto)
                .ToList();
```

Will return a list of strings. That means, your `medidas` variable is a list of strings. In the very next line, you are trying to add a `MuebleVanitorio` object to that. That should give you a compilation error as you are trying to add a different type to the list of strings.

For rendering a dropdown, you need a list of `SelectListItems`s. so update your 
`GetMedidas` method to return that where each item's `Value` will be the `v_Nombre` column value and the `Text` will be the string generated by concatenating `Largo`, `Ancho` and `Alto` property values.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetMedidas()
{
    return db.MuebleVanitorios
                    .Select(m => new SelectListItem { 
                                          Text=m.Largo + "X" + m.Ancho + "X" + m.Alto, 
                                          Value=m.v_Nombre})
                    .ToList();
}
```

and in your action method, now you do not need to create a `SelectList` again. You can directly assign the result of `GetMedidas` method call (*which is a list of `SelectListItem`*)

```
ViewBag.Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio = CombosHelper.GetMedidas();
```

Also it looks like you are not implementing the method(s) of `IDisposable` in your `CombosHelper` class. That should also give you a compile time error

Do you actually really need a extra class and static method in it ? I suggest you re-evaluate that thought and see whether you can create another data helper which can be injected (via DI) to your class so that your code is unit testable.

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing the IDisposable interface correctly, but I'm still not successful, ("There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable <SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio'), my ComboHelpers.cs helps me recover all the dropdown of my project, but it is not necessary that the answer comes from this class @Shyju

Comment: As long as you follow the code in my answer as it is, it should work. I just copied and pasted it into a local project (along with your code from view as it is in the question) and it totally worked for me.

Comment: It is very rare, when I open the project from the view where the dropdown is, it works, but when I open the project from the HomeController and navigate to the view in question, the system fails at run time, why does this happen?

Comment: Try this. Instead of calling the static method in your action method, copy the code in that method to assign the view bag items (`ViewBag.Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio = db.MuebleVanitorios
                    .Select( ... ).ToList();`)

Comment: probe your last recommendation and it does not work either, as it is possible that starting from the view it works, but in time of execution it falls, it is difficult to make this query? you recommend something to me? I can not give as positive your answer or yes?

Comment: When you say it does not work sometime, Are you getting an exception ? What does the inner exception message say ?

Comment: of your response suggestion and the last form I get the same error: "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable <SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio'

Comment: See the working fiddle here. Compare it with your code https://dotnetfiddle.net/0OLS6u